# Jsonresult is failing with parameter in my Ajax Call. Why is it happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

That's my script on my view.

```
    $(function () {
        $('#buttonx').on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Ficha/VerificarPatrocinador',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {i: 100036},
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        //$('#NomePatr').append(item.Nome)
                        $("#NomePatr").val(item.Nome);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

That's my action on my controller.

```
    public JsonResult VerificarPatrocinador(int i)
    {
        var db = new FMDBEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var consulta = db.Tabela_Participante.Where(p => p.ID_Participante == i);
        return Json(consulta.
            Select(x => new
            {
                Nome = x.Nome
            }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'm a newbie in Ajax/Jquery, when I exclude the parameter it is ok, however, when I try to put the data: {i: 100036} in my script and the parameter in my action. It doesn't work. Why is it happening?
The controller is going fine. The parameter even passes, **but I can't return this result in my View.**
Thank you.

Comment: Remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` (your not stringifying the data). And you should also use `url: '@Url.Action("/VerificarPatrocinador", "Ficha")',` to ensure your url's are generated correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [HttpPost] attribute on your controller method

```
[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult VerificarPatrocinador(int i)
    {
        //Write Your Code
    }
```

and change the ajax type attribute from "GET" to "POST" and use JSON.stringify. Also check the url carefully. your ajax should look like this

```
$(function () {
        $('#buttonx').on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Ficha/VerificarPatrocinador',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({i: 100036}),
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        //$('#NomePatr').append(item.Nome)
                        $("#NomePatr").val(item.Nome);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you so much. Md. Mostafizur Rahman. I have had forgotten the "JSON.stringify". Just a last question. What if I want put a texbox id instead of 100036? How would I put it?Thanks. :D

Comment: You do not need `JSON.stringify()` if you remove the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` option (there is no need for either of those). And you certainly do not need `[HttpPost]` on the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @StephenMuecke may be on to something, because I was able to reproduce the (intended) logic with a new project.

The first thing to determine is where the code is going wrong: the server or the client.

Try using the Visual Studio debugger, and placing a breakpoint in `VerificarPatrocinador`.  Then run the client code to see if the breakpoint is hit.  When this succeeds, this means the problem is on the client end.

From there use the web browser's debugger in order to determine what is happening.  Use the `.fail` function on the return result from `.ajax` in order to determine if there was a failure in the HTTP call.  Here is some sample code that you can use to analyze the failure:

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

For more information check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Change following code when ajax success

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
     $("#NomePatr").val(item.Nome);
});
```

because when you are getting data as object of array, array or collection you can iterate using this syntax and then you can pass to var,dom...and so on where you want to display or take.

`jQuery.each()` means `$(selector).each()` you can use for dom element like below syntax: for example

```
    <ul>
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
     $("li").each(function( index ) {
       console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
     });
    </script>
```

Using GET is working fine but if it is not secure because data is visible to user when it submit as query string.

while post have

Key points about data submitted using HttpPost

1. POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource
2. A Submit button will always initiate an HttpPost request.
3. Data is submitted in http request body.
4. Data is not visible in the url.
5. It is more secured but slower as compared to GET.
6. It use heap method for passing form variable
7. It can post unlimited form variables.
8. It is advisable for sending critical data which should not visible to users

so I hope you understand and change ajax type:'GET' to 'POST' if you want.

[$.each() and $(selector).each()](http://dot-net-master.blogspot.in/2016/04/difference-between-each-and-jqueryeach.html)

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
url: 'Ficha/VerificarPatrocinador'
```

to:

```
url: '/Ficha/VerificarPatrocinador'
```

Because when you use this url `"Ficha/VerificarPatrocinador"`, it will call the API from url: `current url + Ficha/VerificarPatrocinador`,so it isn't correct url.

Comment: I changed but it is calling the correct URL. The controller is going fine. The parameter even passes, but I can't return this result in my View.

Comment: You need create breakpoint in you server code when ajax calling, and breakpoint in browser debug when this ajax completed and callback `success` function. You will see the problem.